# Get Stored datas in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to recover my user password and id with an asynchronous function using the AsyncStorage API, only the present code does not execute ...

```
async function getStoredDatas(){
    try{
       return {
           user: await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Store:user'),
           password: await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Store:password')
       };
    }
    catch(e){
       console.log("error:" + e); // never triggered
    }
}

let a = getStoredDatas().then( (datas) => {
    console.log("then: " + datas.user); // never triggered also
});

console.log(a); // Promise with this content: {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

Comment: Give more details. Which error do you get ?

Comment: I do not receive any error, it may be an error in my Javascript code?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot what you see on console log.  It's hard to tell what's wrong with your provided code

Comment: You're javascript seems fine. What do you see if you assign `await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Store:user')` in a value and log it before the `return` ? Maybe there is no item set in AsyncStorage.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the console: https://prnt.sc/hyjdya

Comment: Yes there is nothing in the storage but there should be an undefined return in the console is not it?

Comment: `let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@Store:user');`

Comment: After this line no log is sent

Comment: I think the await does crash function, because before this line all the logs are displayed.

Comment: Here is my import: `import {  AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: The `AsyncStorage` module work only without debug mode.